# pass multiple parameter to controller using jquery (URL)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DivisionList").change(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStudents")', // we are calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#DivisionList").val() },
                success: function (myResult){
                    var row = [];
                    $.each(myResult.students, function (index, item) {
                        row += "<tr><td>" + item.StudentAdmissionID + "</td>"
                        row += "<td>" + item.StudentFirstName + " " + item.StudentMiddleName + " " + item.StudentLastName + "</td>"
                        row += "<td><a href='/TransportationFeeCollections/PayFee?" + "' id=''" + item.RouteId + "&" + "' ids=''" + item.RouteId + "'>Edit </a></td>"
                    });
                    $("#contacts").html(row);
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve Cities.' + ex);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

On Edit Click i want to pass value ID and IDS to controller TransportationFeeCollections and method PayFee , how could i pass two parameter to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used invalid quotes in making URL try the below,

```
 row += "<td><a href='/TransportationFeeCollections/PayFee?"+
           "id="+item.RouteId+"&ids="+item.RouteId+"'>Edit</a></td>";
```

And initialise row as string not an array type, change `row=[]` to `row=''`,

```
success: function (myResult){
     var row = '';// make it string instead of array
     $.each(myResult.students, function (index, item) {
        row += "<tr><td>" + item.StudentAdmissionID + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + item.StudentFirstName + " " + 
                 item.StudentMiddleName + " " + item.StudentLastName + "</td>";
        row += "<td><a href='/TransportationFeeCollections/PayFee?"+
           "id="+item.RouteId+"&ids="+item.RouteId+"'>Edit</a></td>";
        row += "</tr>";// remember the closing tr
     });
     $("#contacts").html(row);
},
```

Comment: thankyou but , its shows some chrome Console Error like PAYEE not Defined <PAYEE-ID> also shows some syntax error

Comment: @Akuria, Replace `<PAYEE-ID>` with yours actual `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Contr")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { par1: val1, par2: val2 },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (myresults) {
                        ur code.....
                    }
                });
```

Controller code as follows :

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string par1, string par2)
{
   Your Code .......
}
```